# Is there any algorithm to compute edit distance between two graphs including same nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-theory, semantic-web, edit-distance

First, I know there has been a lot of works to compute the edit distance between two graphs. But most of the GED algorithms are applied in general cases.

Now considering my case, there are two graphs *G(V1,E1)* and *G(V2,E2)*. *Vk* is a set of nodes which includes k vertices(k is a constant), and *Vk* satisfies both *Vk⊆V1* and *Vk⊆V2*. I want to remain the correspondance between these two graphs when computing the edit distance between them.

I am wondering if there any algorithm aim at this situation? If there is not, does any one have any advice for me? thanks a lot

PS

Assume that vi is a node in Vk. What I am concerned about is that vi remains unchanged when G1 is transformed to G2, which means there is no operation on vi(e.g substitute vi in G1 to u in G2, delete vi in G1, insert vi in G2) during the operations sequence which transform G1 to G2.

Comment: Don't you mean V1⊆Vk and V2⊆Vk ?

Comment: Nope. I mean Vk is a subset of both V1 and V2

Comment: What use is this Vk in solving the problem ? (Except for making it a little more difficult ?)

Comment: Are you assuming that all the edges *Ek* that connect between two nodes in *Vk* are the same in the two graphs?

Comment: Assume that vi is a node in Vk. What I am concerned about is that vi remains unchanged when G1 is transformed to G2, which means there is no operation on vi(e.g substitute vi in G1 to u in G2, delete vi in G1, insert vi in G2) during the operations sequence which transform G1 to G2.

Comment: The edges connect between two nodes in Vk are not necessary to be the same in two graphs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no algorithm to solve your specific problem, because there is no use case and there is no mathematical form. How I would solve this:

1) In the comments you specify Vk unchanged but Ek(1) Ek(2) where Ek(i) are the edges between nodes in Vk for Vi. In that case compute edge add/rem/replace, GED(Vk1, Vk2) ignoring edges out of Vk1/2

2) compute GED(V1-Vk1, V2-Vk2) ignoring the edges between Vi-Vki and Vki. Where V1-Vk1 is the graph V1 after removing all nodes in Vk and all edges linked to Vk

3) compute GED(E(V1-Vk1 <-> Vk1), E(V2-Vk2 <-> Vk2)), that is, compute the GED of replacing "edges linking V1-Vk1 and Vk1" with "edges linking V2-Vk2 and Vk2".

4) Add the 3 GED together.